# Word for the final instance of awarding a perpetual trophy

Tags: adjectives, terminology, vocabulary

We have a perpetual trophy that has been awarded for almost four decades. The Award is being retired, and presented to a worthy recipient one last time. How do I refer to this instance of the awarding? For example, I could say the final award or ultimate reward or the concluding iteration of the award, but I would love to know if there is a correct or more evocative word that could be used.

Comment: Do you mean a recurring trophy? Are not trophies always awarded in perpetuity each time they are given?

Comment: @tchrist In my experience a *perpetual* trophy is one that is not kept by the awardee *in perpetuity*, but is passed on to the next awardee. See for example https://www.designawards.net.au/perpetual-trophies-awards/

Comment: I don't think there's anything specific, anything that indicates finality should work. "Final" seems fine to me.

Comment: I think *finale* is your word.

Comment: I think you'd normally just say something like *X team were given the trophy to keep* or *in perpetuity* or *for good*, depending on how highfalutin you were being. Although you might still want to add that the trophy would not be awarded any more (some trophies are given to keep if a team does something like win them three times, but a new one is subsequently awarded; this used to happen with the Football World Cup but no idea if it still does). But yeah, I don't think there's a single word or short phrase.

Comment: How about the terminal award?